# Passing values and events

Tags: c#, events

I am using  C# 
I have 02 Forms ,Form O1 Contain 03 buttons And Form 2 contain TabControl With 3 tabs 
How to Make tab 1 is the active tab when i click on The first button on form 1 and the second tab will activate when i click on the second button and the same for the last button 
Any help .i dont have anu idea .is it possible to do it by passing parameters ?

Comment: I think you should look into MDI Forms http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7aw8zc76(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the instance of the form and then you can access the controls on that form - you need to create the controls as Public in order to access in another form.

Edit: It's not always a good idea to expose the controls on the form. So, instead of making the controls public, you can just create a property in that class and set the selected index from that property. For ex:

```
public class Form2
{
    public int TabSelectedIndex 
    { 
       set { tabControl.TabIndex = value; }
    }
}

public class Form1
{
    private Form2 _form2 = new Form2();

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _form2.TabSelectedIndex = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: how we create the controls public in there properties u mean ??

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to Form2.  Something liek..  `void SetActiveTabIndex(Int32 index) {TabControl1.ActiveTab = ...}`

Comment: the tabcontrol is in  another form

Comment: edited.  place the new method in the form that contains the tab control.

Answer (score 0):

Set the "Modifiers" property of your tabcontrol on Form 2 to "Public" Then on Form 1 use the following code:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2 ();

//you will need to call frm.Show() somewhere to display form2

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2.tabControl2.SelectedIndex = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a public variable in a public static class, when you click on a button in Form1, just change the value of this variable to indicate that a certain button has been clicked (you can for example set the value of the public variable to 0 when clicking button1, 1 when clicking button2 ...etc).
Now in Form2 , Read the value of that variable , and activate the suitable Tab according to that value.

Comment: in form 2 who's the Event that will capture the variable

Comment: sorry I assumed that Form1 is open and you will click a button in it then Form2 will open, it doesn't make sense to open two forms and change one from another!.

Answer (score 0):

On Form1 add handlers for each button's click event:

```
foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (f == Form2)
            {
                f.SelectTab(0)
            }
        }
```

On Form2 add a method:

```
public void SelectTab(int tabIdx)
{
    this.TabControl1.SelectedIndex = tabIdx;
}
```